# Fourier transform of inverse of determinant of 1+ skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, skew-symmetric-matrices

I have a very specific question concerning the Fourier transform of certain determinant function of a skew-symmetric matrix: Write $SSym(n)$ for the space of $n\times n$ skew-symmetric real matrices. I want to evaluate the Fourier transform of the function $F(x):=\mathrm{det}(1+x)^{-1}$ for $x\in SSym(n)$, in other words, for $y\in SSym(n)$, what is the following integral?

$$\widehat{F}(y):=\int_{SSym(n)}e^{-2i\mathrm{Tr}(x\cdot\,^{\mathrm{t}}y)}\frac{1}{\mathrm{det}(1+x)}dx$$

For the special case $n=2$, this is easy: write $y=\begin{pmatrix}0 & b \\-b & 0\end{pmatrix}$, then it is easy to see $\widehat{F}(y)=e^{-4|b|}$(perhaps up to some explicit non-zero constant multiple).

Note that $\mathrm{det}(1+x)^2=\mathrm{det}(1+x)\mathrm{det}(1+\,^{\mathrm{t}}x)=\mathrm{det}(1+x\cdot\,^{\mathrm{t}}x)>0$ because $1+x\cdot\,^{\mathrm{t}}x$ is always positive definite. So $F(x)$ is well-defined everywhere and a smooth function on $SSym(n)$. Concerning the convergence of the integral, one can argue as follows: each skew-symmetric matrix $x$ is of the form $x=\,^{\mathrm{t}}AXA$ for some orthogonal matrix $A\in\mathrm{O}(n)$ and $X$ is a block-diagonal matrix, whose diagonal blocks are of the form $\begin{pmatrix}0 & b \\-b & 0\end{pmatrix}$(the converse is clearly true). Moreover $\mathrm{det}(1+x)=\mathrm{det}(1+X)$. Write $S$ for the set of all such $X$.  Then we can rewrite $\widehat{F}(y)$ as follows:

$$\widehat{F}(y)=\int_{S}\frac{1}{\mathrm{det}(1+X)}dX\int_{\mathrm{O}(n)}e^{-2i\mathrm{Tr}(\,^{\mathrm{t}}AXA\,^{\mathrm{t}}y)}dA$$

(Here the inner integral should be over $\mathrm{O}(n)/\mathrm{O}(2)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$, but we ignore such issue)Now the inner integral is over a compact group and the integrand has bounded absolute value, thus the integral, as a function on $y$ and $X$, is uniformly bounded above. Then the convergence of the integral $\int_S\frac{1}{\mathrm{det}(1+X)}dX$ is reduced to the case $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$ because $\mathrm{det}(1+\begin{pmatrix}0 & t \\-t & 0\end{pmatrix})=1+t^2$. This last integral is clearly convergent.

Of course, maybe one way is to compute first the inner integral $\int_{\mathrm{O}(n)}e^{-2i\mathrm{Tr}(\,^{\mathrm{t}}AXA\,^{\mathrm{t}}y)}dA$, but except for some obvious properties of this function on $X$ and $y$, I could not go further. Moreover it is easy to see $\widehat{F}(\,^{\mathrm{t}}AyA)=\widehat{F}(y)$ for any $A\in\mathrm{O}(n)$, thus we can just assume that $y$ is an element in $S$.

Comment: An antisymmetric matrix has eigenvalues either $0$ or pure imaginary $a_ki$, $\det(I+X)$ is $\chi(-1)=(a_1+1)(a_2+1)...$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic polynomial of $X$. Isn't possible to take advantage of this representation ?

Comment: @JeanMarie that is a nice idea, indeed, when I show the convergence of the Fourier transform, this fact is implicitly used, in particular, to reduce to the case of $n=2$. However to evaluate the Fourier transform, we also need to cope with the trace of the product $x\cdot y$, which seems not easy just using eigenvalues.

Comment: In connection with my remark, and although your integral is not a principal value, do you know the [Glasser's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem)?

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for the informative reference that I am not aware of. But I have not figured out how to treat the higher dimension case using this theorem. The main problem for me is that there is no easy way to deal with the function $e^{2i\mathrm{Tr}(\,^{\mathrm{t}}AXA\,^{\mathrm{t}}y)}$ even if both $X=(\mathrm{diag}(\begin{pmatrix}0 & X_i \\ -X_i & 0\end{pmatrix}))$ and $y$ (with $y_i$ similar to those $X_i$) are in $S$. In fact, if we write $A$ in block matrix with $2\times2$-blocks, $A=(A_{i,j})$, then $\mathrm{Tr}(\,^{\mathrm{t}}AXA\,^{\mathrm{t}}y)=\sum_{i,j}X_iy_j det(A_{i,j})$.

Comment: I see... Besides, another idea (maybe as unpracticable as the others...): $\dfrac{1}{\det(I+A)}=\det(I+A)^{-1}=\det(I-A+A^2-A^3+\cdots$ and then use an approximation approach...

Comment: Crossposted to [mathoverflow.se] on 2022-03-13: [Fourier transform of inverse of determinant of 1+ skew-symmetric matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/q/418064).